# Camera and microphone stopped working on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, microphone

I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.1 an suddenly the camera and microphone (to make calls or send voice messages) stopped working. When I try to hit the button to take a picture with the camera, nothing happens (I only see the "press" animation of the button). Yes, the phone fell down from the table once, but I don't know if the camera and microphone stopped working immediately after this.

The strange thing is, that I can send photos with the Signal app. So the camera doesn't seem to be damaged, right?

Updates are installed. There is also free storage space (so the storage is not full).

Any other things I can/should try?

EDIT: When trying a test call with the "Phone Diagnostics" app, the app crashes.

Comment: Can you only send existing photos with Signal or also shoot new ones? Did you already restart your phone?

Comment: Yes, restarted. I can take and send new photos. I think the main issue is with the microphone. As written in the update above, the diagnostics app crashes when testing a call.